# Replace a randomly recurrent string among floats?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, replace, floating-point

I have a large text file that looks like this:

```
WHAT
EVER
0.00000904
17577

FOO
BAR
7.00000031
426
```

Occasionally, one of the fourth values is less than 1, and looks like this:

```
MORE
FOO
8.3894983
<1
```

These are being converted into a dictionary using this code:

```
output = {x[0].replace("\n","-"):map(float,x[1:]) for x in data}
```

and looks like this:

```
{'FOOBAR': [7.00000031, 426.0], 'WHATEVER': [9.04e-06, 17577.0]}
```

I need to convert the string '<1' into the float 0.0, since it is returning

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: <1
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: what does your third example output currently? does the string '<1' get added to the dictionary?

Comment: Show us your code.

Answer (score 1):

In your code where you add value to the list, make a check like:

```
0.0 if num == '<1' else float(num)
```

For example:

```
>>> num = '<1'  # Value as `'<1'`
>>> 0.0 if num == '<1' else float(num)
0.0   # returned 0.0

>>> num = '3.456'  # Value as `'3.456'`
>>> 0.0 if num == '<1' else float(num)
3.456   # Returned float value
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading the file, assign the read file to a variable one at a time. Then, do this:

```
#Read the file and assign the output to FOO
if FOO == "<1":
    FOO = 0.0
#CONTINUE WITH FOO
```

This uses python's dynamic typing.